# get data using a condition in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
WITH DATA
     AS ( select ACCT_ID_1,  ACCT_ID, ACCT_ID_2 ... from two tables joined by criteria ),
DATA1
     AS (SELECT D1.*
           FROM DATA D1
          WHERE ACCT_ID_1 = ACCT_ID AND ACCT_ID_1 = '101'),
DATA2
     AS (SELECT D2.*
           FROM DATA D2
          WHERE ACCT_ID_2 = ACCT_ID AND ACCT_ID_2 = '101')
```

I need to get data1 if there is data in data1 ( no data from data2 ) else I need to get from data2. Is it possible using SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably how I'd do it:

```
WITH data1 AS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM dual
  WHERE 1=2 -- Set to 1 to reverse result
)
, data2 AS (
  SELECT 2
  FROM dual  
)
SELECT *
FROM data1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM data2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM data1
)
```

Posted on [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/4513/0) as an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ACCT_ID_1,  ACCT_ID, ACCT_ID_2, ...,
  IF EXISTS (SELECT D1.*
       FROM DATA D1
      WHERE ACCT_ID_1 = ACCT_ID AND ACCT_ID_1 = '101')
  THEN (SELECT D1.ACCT_ID_1
       FROM DATA D1
      WHERE ACCT_ID_1 = ACCT_ID AND ACCT_ID_1 = '101')
  ELSE (SELECT D2.ACCT_ID_2
       FROM DATA D2
       WHERE ACCT_ID_2 = ACCT_ID AND ACCT_ID_2 = '101')
  END IF
```